# Cannot edit .obj files on recent Xcode version, but on older Xcode version it works perfect

Tags: xcode, scenekit, mesh, .obj

When I try to edit or even convert most kind of .obj files (i.Ex. from Blender) the recent version of Xcode (in this case 12.2, on mac OS Catalina) is not capable anymore doing anything with that .obj file. Even the Finder file handler does not show any preview.

The workaraund is to take an older Version of Xcode (in this case 10.0, on mac OS High Sierra) and doing the stuff there.

Finally I can convert the .obj file to .scn and make further editing with the recent Xcode.

Here are some print Screens that shows the problem:

[image: Recent Xcode displays nothing]

[image: Old Xcode displays initial model]

[image: Recent Xcode shows converted model by older Xcode Version]

Is it possible, that I do something wrong, or has anyone faced the same issue?

Can it be fixed somehow?

Here is what the mac OS file handler says:

[image: .obj file in Finder on Catalina]

[image: .obj file in Finder on High Sierra]

[image: .scn file in Finder on Catalina]

PS: The .obj file can be used directly within i.Ex. SceneKit by loading it via Scene-Named or the Model IO. There is no issue at all with the file - it's just the visual scene-graph editor that causes problems with the recent Xcode.

Comment: Annoyingly I have the same issue :-/